# P.O. check list

Tags: excel, vba

I need users to be able to fill in one row to generate a P.O., and when the P.O. is generated the row below would be unhidden. The P.O. depends on column C, E and G to be filled in.

This code only unhides a row if one of the requirements are met. It also makes the workbook lag.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Row < 14 Or Target.Row > 5000 Or Target.Column < 3 Or Target.Column < 5 Or Target.Column <> 7 Then GoTo ExitMe
  Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = False

ExitMe:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I need one row to be filled in at a time so the P.O. can be generated properly. If there is a better way please let me know.

This macro also conflicts with my macro for protecting changed cells when the worksheet is saved. This is the error that appears: `Run-time error '1004': Unable to set hidden property of the Range class.`

It is placed in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Option Explicit

Private bRangeEdited As Boolean
Private WithEvents ws As Worksheet


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ws = Range("A14:Y3000").Parent
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sMSG As String

    sMSG = "saving the workbook will lock the cells you have entered data into." & vbLf
    sMSG = sMSG & "Do you want to go ahead ?"
    If Not bRangeEdited Then GoTo Xit
    If Not Me.ReadOnly Then
        With Range("A14:Y3000")
            If MsgBox(sMSG, vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
                GoTo Xit
            End If
            .Parent.Unprotect "password"
            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address <> .Address Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = True
                bRangeEdited = False
            End If
            .Parent.Protect "password"
        End With
    End If
Xit:
End Sub

Private Sub ws_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A14:Y3000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        bRangeEdited = True
    End If
End Sub
```